# Restricting access to AWS EC2 metadata for specific docker containers

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, docker

I'm running docker on AWS EC2 instances, and I'd like to block certain containers from accessing
the EC2 instance metadata (at IP address 169.254.169.254). I thought I could do this by running
those containers as a specific user (eg userx), in the presence of the following ip tables rule:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner userx -d 169.254.169.254 -j DROP
```

This blocks the connnection as expected when the container is run with host networking:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --network host -u $(id -u userx):$(id -g userx) appropriate/curl  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
...blocks..
```

But sadly allows the connection when the container runs within it's own network

```
$ docker run -it --rm -u $(id -u userx):$(id -g userx) appropriate/curl  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
...show metadata...
```

How can I make this work? Or alternatively, is there some other technique that will give specific containers full network access whilst blocking the instance metadata?

Comment: What is your problem, and what are you trying to achieve? Blocking instance metadata isn't an aim or a problem, it's your solution to problem or need you have't stated.

Comment: My problem is that I have certain containers which need full internet access (as they need to fetch arbitrary public internet URLs). However, if they can access the ec2 metadata, there is the potential to leak privileged information. I need to prevent this.

Comment: Your need for internet access and EC2 metadata seem completely unrelated to me. Can you please edit your post to make it crystal clear the problem you're having or what you're trying to achieve, without making any assumptions around the best solution / implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that `OUTPUT` doesn't catch packets coming out of containers. `FORWARD` does.

Why is that?

Every Docker container runs in its own network namespace. Every network namespace has its own routing table and iptables rules, and behaves exactly as if it was a separate physical machine.

In iptables:

- `INPUT` matches packets going to local processes
- `FORWARD` matches packets coming in one network interface and going out another one (being routed through).
- `OUTPUT` matches packets coming from local processes

The key is that "local process" means "a process in this network namespace", not "a process in this machine".

Let's analyze what's going on:

- Packets are generated by processes in the Docker container's network namespace.
- They go through the iptables `OUTPUT` chain in the container's network namespace iptables. (which is empty!)
- They get routed out of the `veth` interface.
- They arrive to the host's network namespace from the `veth` interface.
- The host network namespace consults the routing table and decides they need to go out of e.g. `eth0`.
- They go through the iptables `FORWARD` chain in the host's network namespace.
- They go out `eth0`.

Therefore, the solution is putting your rule in the `FORWARD` chain instead.

The issue is that `-m owner` doesn't work in `FORWARD`. According to `man iptables-extensions`:

> This match is only valid in the OUTPUT and POSTROUTING chains. Forwarded packets do not have any socket associated with them.

You can either hardcode the container's IP addresses, or put containers you want filtered in a special network, and match the whole range. Something similar to this should work:

```
    # single container
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.17.0.4 -d 169.254.169.254 -j DROP

    # or entire network
    iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.17.0.0/16 -d 169.254.169.254 -j DROP
```

Also, using `owner` is probably not a good idea either way, because processes inside docker containers can change their uid's via eg setuid binaries (like sudo), if there are any in the image.

Comment: Thanks - this is really helpful answer. One question though - in the above you say "the solution is putting your rule in the FILTER chain", yet your examples add rules to the "FORWARD" chain. Is this difference intentional?

Comment: @timbod My bad, I meant the FORWARD chain. "filter" is the table, not a chain. Fixed! :)